# Complex JS Object populate clickable list and form

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms

In this code I bring in a String that is not structured and I parse it into a JS object. I now need to apply it to a web form.

[Here is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T59fL/1/). It shows the Parsed/Structured object hierarchy is and alerts an example of a targeting item.

1. Create a clickable list of key items(I.e. Button, Image, Label, etc
2. Clicking the list item, populate a form with the values
3. Modify the values and save back to the object

There are some caveats:

1. There are duplicate keys. I don't know how to make them unique while still keeping the data integrity their. I cannot nest them. The only thing I can think of is append a unique id to them
2. Ideally the form will dynamically generate the fields based on the fields in the object. (I.e. 'Button' has width, height, transition, and name, where as 'Label' has a different set of fields.
3. Some of the elements are nested(I.e. 'Scroll' has its own 'Buttons' and 'Labels'

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The code below does create a List of elements, but I can't get it to load the values into a form based on my click.

Here is the code

```
    //Parse String
var str = 'View\n{\n    Name: View1;\n    Image\n    {\n        BackgroundImage: Image.gif;\n        Position: 0, 0;\n        Width: 320;\n        Height: 480;\n    }\n\n    Button\n    {\n        BackgroundImage: Button.gif;\n        Transition: View2;\n        Position: 49, 80;\n        Width: 216;\n        Height: 71;\n    }\n\n    Button\n    {\n        BackgroundImage: Button2.gif;\n        Position: 65, 217;\n        Width: 188;\n        Height: 134;\n    }\n\n    Label\n    {\n        Position: 106, 91;\n        Width: 96;\n        Height: 34;\n        Text: "Button";\n        FontSize: 32;\n        Color: 0.12549, 0.298039, 0.364706, 1;\n    }\n    Scroll\n    {\n        Position: 106, 91;\n        Width: 96;\n        Height: 34;\n        Button{\n            BackgroundImage: Button2.gif;\n            Position: 65, 217;\n            Width: 188;\n            Height: 134;\n        }\n        Button{\n            BackgroundImage: Button2.gif;\n            Position: 65, 217;\n            Width: 188;\n     \n      Height: 134;\n        }\n\n    }\n\n}';

str = str.replace(/(\w+)\s*\{/g, "$1:{"); // add in colon after each named object
str = str.replace(/\}(\s*\w)/g, "},$1"); // add comma before each new named object
str = str.replace(/;/g, ","); // swap out semicolons with commas
str = str.replace(/,(\s+\})/g, "$1"); // get rid of trailing commas
str = str.replace(/([\d\.]+(, [\d\.]+)+)/g, "[$1]"); // create number arrays
str = str.replace(/"/g, ""); // get rid of all double quotes
str = str.replace(/:\s+([^\[\d\{][^,]+)/g, ':"$1"');  // create strings

$("#parseList").html(str);

var objStr;
eval("objStr={" + str + "};");

//console.log(objStr.View.Button)
//alert(objStr.View.Scroll.Button.Width);
//End Parse String

$(document).ready(function () {

    //Build Initial Object LIst
    var initObjectList = '<div id="prePop">';
    $.each(objStr.View, function (k, v) {
        initObjectList += '<div class="inLineObjects">' + '<div class="key">' + k + '</div>' + '</div>';

    });
    initObjectList += '</div>';
    $('#code').append(initObjectList)
```

Example of Object Output:

```
    View:{
    Name:"View1",
    Image:{
        BackgroundImage:"Image.gif",
        Position: [0, 0],
        Width: 320,
        Height: 480
    },

    Button:{
        BackgroundImage:"Button.gif",
        Transition:"View2",
        Position: [49, 80],
        Width: 216,
        Height: 71
    },

    Button:{
        BackgroundImage:"Button2.gif",
        Position: [65, 217],
        Width: 188,
        Height: 134
    },

    Label:{
        Position: [106, 91],
        Width: 96,
        Height: 34,
        Text:"Button",
        FontSize: 32,
        Color: [0.12549, 0.298039, 0.364706, 1]
    },
    Scroll:{
        Position: [106, 91],
        Width: 96,
        Height: 34,
        Button:{
            BackgroundImage:"Button2.gif",
            Position: [65, 217],
            Width: 188,
            Height: 134
        },
        Button:{
            BackgroundImage:"Button2.gif",
            Position: [65, 217],
            Width: 188,

      Height: 134
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Yikes, use the `parse` method of the `JSON` object to parse that, no need to work it out with all your own regex.

Comment: What's the actual question here?  In general you'll get a much better response on Stack Overflow if you keep your questions as specific as possible rather than including a ton of stuff and saying "Any help would be greatly appreciated".  We like giving help here, you don't need to ask ;-)  But you do need to (or at least you'll get better answers if you) make it as easy as possible for us to help you.

Comment: You have no control over this output? If the server is going to send you json, it needs to send you _valid_ json in the correct format (duplicate keys are not valid in JSON spec). Or maybe I'm missing something here, is the input in any kind of specific format (css)?

Comment: Just to add to @Austin's comment, `JSON.parse` is available already in most modern browsers.  If you need to support older browsers, you can download your own (functionally equivalent) version from `www.json.org`.

Comment: @machineghost thank you. The thing I am having most trouble with is a) getting this current out to populate a form that has inputs for each. In this code, I already create a list, I just need to be able to click on an item i.e. 'Image' and get a form that has input fields for each k,v within the selected item and populated with the current values. Upon modifying the inputs, they will be saved back to the Object. Make sense?.. jfyi - the string that I parse in was never meant to be a data object, its an instruction script for a program I have. I now just want to edit the values with a web form.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Object into list and form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062326/javascript-object-into-list-and-form)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, probably your best bet is to build the form for each `objStr.View,` as you build it, but keep that form hidden (CSS `display:none`).  Then, when the user clicks on one, all you have to do is `$(thatForm).show()` and you're set.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Having to maintain a set of forms around this data. I was trying to create a form that loops through the object and creates inputs for the fields.

Comment: You absolutely can still do that: when you are building the form, instead of building it right there, create a function that builds it based on the options, and then invoke that function.  That way you only have one bit of code which generates the forms for every object, but you get an individual form for each object ready and waiting for you hidden on the page.

Comment: Sorry. I have not done that before. Can you point me in the right direction? Will the List code I have be sufficient for that part? How would I populate a dynamic form based on my selection?     Everything below //Build Initial Object LIst

Comment: I believe I figured it out. Feedback on the solution would be great. http://jsfiddle.net/kHysL/

Answer (score 0):

Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/kHysL/

Here is my solution:

```
    var str = 'View\n{\n    Name: View1;\n    Image\n    {\n        BackgroundImage: Image.gif;\n        Position: 0, 0;\n        Width: 320;\n        Height: 480;\n    }\n\n    Button\n    {\n        BackgroundImage: Button.gif;\n        Transition: View2;\n        Position: 49, 80;\n        Width: 216;\n        Height: 71;\n    }\n\n    Button\n    {\n        BackgroundImage: Button2.gif;\n        Position: 65, 217;\n        Width: 188;\n        Height: 134;\n    }\n\n    Label\n    {\n        Position: 106, 91;\n        Width: 96;\n        Height: 34;\n        Text: "Button";\n        FontSize: 32;\n        Color: 0.12549, 0.298039, 0.364706, 1;\n    }\n    Scroll\n    {\n        Position: 106, 91;\n        Width: 96;\n        Height: 34;\n        Button{\n            BackgroundImage: Button2.gif;\n            Position: 65, 217;\n            Width: 188;\n            Height: 134;\n        }\n        Button{\n            BackgroundImage: Button2.gif;\n            Position: 65, 217;\n            Width: 188;\n     \n      Height: 134;\n        }\n\n    }\n\n}';

str = str.replace(/(\w+)\s*\{/g, "$1:{"); // add in colon after each named object
str = str.replace(/\}(\s*\w)/g, "},$1"); // add comma before each new named object
str = str.replace(/;/g, ","); // swap out semicolons with commas
str = str.replace(/,(\s+\})/g, "$1"); // get rid of trailing commas
str = str.replace(/([\d\.]+(, [\d\.]+)+)/g, "[$1]"); // create number arrays
str = str.replace(/"/g, ""); // get rid of all double quotes
str = str.replace(/:\s+([^\[\d\{][^,]+)/g, ':"$1"');  // create strings

$("#parseList").html(str);

var objStr;
eval("objStr={" + str + "};");

//End Parse String

$(document).ready(function () {
    var selected;
    //Build Initial Object LIst
    var initObjectList = '<div id="main">';
    $.each(objStr.View, function (k, v) {
        initObjectList += '<div>' + k + '</div>';

    });
    initObjectList += '</div>';
    $('#main').append(initObjectList)

    $(document).on('click', '#main div div', function () {
        var index = $('#main div div').index(this);

        $(this).click(function () {
            $('#form div').remove();
            codeSnippet = "";
            x = $('#main div div').toArray();
            codeSnippet = (x[index].innerHTML);
            console.log(codeSnippet);

            var initObjectDetail = '<div id="form">';
            $.each(objStr.View[codeSnippet], function (k, v) {
                initObjectDetail += '<div>' + k + '</div>' + '<input value=' + v + '>' + '</input>';
                console.log(v);

            });
            initObjectList += '</div>';
            $('#form').append(initObjectDetail)
        });

    });
});​
```